# Domain DNS settings do not work behind DS-Lite connection

Tags: networking, dns, ipv6

I would like to access my Raspberry from the internet which is provided to my FritzBox with a DS-Lite connection. After some struggle with IPv6 addresses I got it work through the MyFritz service which gives me the following address to access my PI:

```
raspberrypi.71zpsngawonyba5d.myfritz.net
```

With this I have access to the PI from within my own network as well as through mobile data from my phone. Now I would like to address the PI with my own domain and here things start to get weired. I tried to gather all DNS information from the above domain which basically is only an `AAAA` record. Since my DNS provider only supports CNAMEs for sub domains (no CNAME flattening) I created the following DNS settings for my domain:

```
@    TTL 3600    <PI IPv6 Address>
*    TTL 3600    <PI IPv6 Address>
```

With this settings I'm able to connect to my PI through the mobile network on my phone but not from within my home network. When I try to open my domain through Chrome I get the following error message:

```
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

I guess (and I might be wrong here) that the DS-Lite connection is the problem here. My request is probably send from the NAT of my internet provider, therefore it uses IPv4 and it can't find an `A` record to send the request to.

My question now is why does the access work from the myfritz subdomain? Did I miss any DNS settings here or are they doing some kind of `4to6` tunneling in the background? I also tried CNAME flattening with Cloudflare and that works great so I do not think tunneling is the right call here. Unfortunately I would like to use other ports than HTTP and HTTPS so I can not use their service.

Comment: Is the Pi in the same home network as the Chrome browser, or is it hosted somewhere else? Does your PC (the one with Chrome in it) show working IPv6 support when it's connected to your home network – does it have an IPv6 address with the same prefix; does it have an IPv6 default route (a ::/0 route); do the various "test IPv6" sites work?

Comment: Yes, the PI and Chrome browser are in the same home network, both share the same prefix and IPv6 sites work as well. I'm not sure about the default route however

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after some long research I got it work:

The problem was actually my FritzBox which uses DNS rebind protection which means that it does not allow resolving of private IP addresses. This was no problem during IPv4 days since you would use the public IP of your FritzBox but today with IPv6 internal IPs are also public.

You can read [here](https://avm.de/service/wissensdatenbank/dok/FRITZ-Box-7390/663_DNS-Auflosung-privater-IP-Adressen-nicht-moglich) (only in Germany sorry) how to enable it. The site does not state if it also supports wildcard inputs in the Web interface. I'll try and update this answer as soon as I can tell.